# Volley's StringRequest()

Tags: android, networking, android-volley, httpresponse

As per my knowledge server can response in either XML or JSON format only ,is it true? if it is then how Volley's `StringRequest()` works?

Answer (score 0):

XML and JSON are formatted Strings.  A `http` request will always return a String.  If you are designing the requesting system you should know the format that is expected within that String (the body of the response in particular), and it is for you to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, Config."Url",
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                try {

                    val obj = JSONObject(response)

                    if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {

                        val userssListArray = obj.getJSONArray("arrayanme")

                        for (i in 0 until userssListArray.length()) {
                            var usersObj = userssListArray.getJSONObject(i)

                        }


                    } else {

                        if (obj.getString("message") == "Your login expired please re login") {
                            val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                            finish()
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Network Error Try Again...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }) {
        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()

            return params
        }
    }
    stringRequest.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
            15000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)
    //adding request to queue
    VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
```

this is how volley string request works